# Why do the street labels appear in duplicate on my map- QGIS Training Manual 3. Module: Classifying Vector Data 3.2. Lesson: Labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, references

QGIS Training Manual 3. Module: Classifying Vector Data 3.2. Lesson: Labels

I'm doing the QGIS Tutorial on labelling but i'm encountering an error. The street labels appear in duplicate in red and also in my chosen colour. I have been unable so far to correct this problem. Is it a bug? I'm using the latest QGIS version 3.32.1-Lima. Screenshot of map is attached to demonstrate.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Red displays hidden labels for debugging. This button will help you. [image]